# Heroku doesn't display my latest django template change

Tags: django, heroku

A bit of a classic works in dev but not production. Never had an issue with heroku not working if it works in dev before.  I recently made a commit in django app which changed a png to an svg and change the template accordingly - ie just 2 file changes in the commit. Then realised I needed a quick additional change in the template and force pushed the change to origin and then to heroku.
However now heroku just doesn't display that template (and the image within it).  Everything else works.  Tried to do another change to the template and push another commit to see if that would fix it.

I've rolled back heroku for now, but not sure how best to go about determining where the error is?

Comment: Try clearing your cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was nothing in the logs.

Best way to resolve was to do. 
`heroku run bash`
then `ls`

This issue was a filename was capitalised on the remote repo but not locally.

Answer (score 1):

Redo the commit, push it to heroku again and let the site run.

Then do

```
heroku logs
```

You should be able to find the error messages there if there are any